# how to replace all text in c3js with html?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am using c3js on a site that also uses google translate. Google translate finds all of the svg text, translates it and wraps it in font tags which then stops it being displayed as svg text can't have font tags.

I can stop the graph being translated by setting a class of notranslate but I would like the graphs text to be translated.

I can get round this in d3.js by setting all the text to html instead of svg, is this possible with the c3js library or is there a better way?

Comment: The bigger issue is why does Google Translate break things so badly.  I would have expected that SVG should just ignore unrecognized tags, but I tested the generated code in Firefox and it has the same behaviour. Demo page for those with an English system language to test out Google translate's mangling: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nfvp2dzr/2/show/

Comment: P.S.  Google bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=443624